# Compound events: pick cards at random

Tags: probability

Every card holds one of these letters: M,A,T,H,E,M,A,T,I,C,S. 
What is the probability of picking an M card at random, without replacement, and then an A card,at random, without looking?

1. My answer is $2/55$, but I want to know how you solve it from your own perspective?
2. What could the phrase "without replacement" mean ($2$ events can not exchange their order,...)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would say, your solution is correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phrase "without replacement" means the card that's been picked is not going back into the pile. Probability of picking M first is $2 \over 11$ and probability to pick A afterwards is $2 \over 10$ (only $10$ cards left) so your answer is correct. If it was "with replacement", the probability to pick A would have been $2 \over 11$.